# How to load Loader on Every Route in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, loader, angular7-router

Hello i want to put loader on every route link , when route link change show  loader until all its component not load with api data.

**Structure of Component**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

inside `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` i have other child component like and its data come from api.

```
<app-component1></app-component1>
<app-component2></app-component2>
```

so my problem is i cant put loader for page(route) wise if page load loader show and hide after all component load with dynamic(api) data

Comment: Take a look example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-ui-loader)

Comment: try https://github.com/kKen94/ngx-progress

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to RouterEvents to know when a route navigation is started to completed. You would also need a loader component in your AppComponent outside of your router-outlet and a flag to show/hide the loader. You can control loader visibility across the application using a LoaderService.

**LoaderService**

```
export class LoaderService {

  isLoaderShown = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() { }

  public showLoader() {
    this.isLoaderShown.next(true);
  }

  public hideLoader() {
    this.isLoaderShown.next(false);
  }

}
```

You can use this LoaderService to show or hide the loader from anywhere in the application.

Update your AppComponent to add a new loader component. LoaderComponent just needs to contain a loader of your choice.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-loader *ngIf="showLoader"></app-loader>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Now we can control the loader display using the `showLoader` flag in AppComponent.

**AppComponent**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  showLoader = false;

  constructor(
    private loaderService: LoaderService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService.isLoaderShown.subscribe(isLoaderShown => this.showLoader = isLoaderShown);
    this.router.events.subscribe(routerEvent => {
      if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.loaderService.showLoader();
      } else if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.loaderService.hideLoader();
      } else if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel) {
        this.loaderService.hideLoader();
        // Handle cancel
      } else if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
        this.loaderService.hideLoader();
        // Handle error
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now, whenever a router navigation starts, we are showing the loader and hiding when navigation ends. 
However, this doesn't take the API load times into consideration. For that, you could remove the `this.loaderService.hideLoader();` from the `NavigationEnd` and add it in your API call subscription. This is the reason why we add it as a service. You can inject it onto your API Service and hide loader.

```
this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe(result => {
    // Perform operations with the result
    this.loaderService.hideLoader();
});
```

So, loader will be shown when navigation starts and when the API call result is available in service, loader can be hidden.